# Running php exec() for background process

Tags: php, linux, bash, zend-framework

I have set up a line of code in my class to run a function in the background using the following line on my linux server:

`$cmd = "nohup wget -q <-url here-> /dev/null 2>&1 &")";
$exec = exec( 'bash -c "'.$cmd.'"' );`

(with the url just pointing to my script)

This is working fine and doing what I want it do, however everytime this runs it is creating a new file in my root (public_html) and they are all numbered like 10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 etc.

Does anybody know how I can stop these being created?

Also if this is bad practice and anybody wants to suggest a better way of doing something like this, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cmd = "nohup wget -q <-url here-> -O /dev/null 2>&1 &")";
$exec = exec( 'bash -c "'.$cmd.'"' );
```

note the -O flag, with which you tell wget where to save the downloaded file. with this, you direct it to /dev/null and therefore delete it.

Comment: you could also just use file_get_contents("your_url") directly in PHP, but that's synchronous - you'll have to wait for it to finish. I understand there is a way to asynchronously fetch websites with curl. That would give you a method that doesn't need the exec-command. however, personally I don't have experience with curl. http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php